# Изверг и извергать — почему один корень?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Изверг — жестокий человек, извергать — выбрасывать из себя что-то. Вроде бы ничего общего по смыслу, а слова явно однокоренные. Или все-таки нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Абсолютно верно, однокоренные.Изверг - извергнутый из человеческого общества. Извергнуть-выбросить.Изверг - старославянское заимствование, в русск. памятниках встречается с 14 века.Происхождение не установлено точно: возможно, калька с греч."выкидыш", возможно,от глагола извергти (от индоевроп., затем праславянского)уже в русском - споры о времени: что от чего - изверг от извергать или наоборот.

Comment: Людмила, не совсем понятно, если изверг - заимствование, то как оно может быть *однокоренным* с исходно славянским? Насколько понимаю, слова, пришедшие в язык *разными* путями родственными в этом языке (т.е. в русском) родственными не считаются.  
Вы имеете в виду родство на праславянском уровне или все-таки именно то, что они однокоренные уже в русском?

Это не просто терминологический спор, какие слова считать родственными, это вопрос понимания смысла.

По сути же - согласен.

Comment: Я написала "однокоренные", потому что больше верю славянской версии, а если даже и заимств. из греч., то всё равно значения совпали и "изверг" и "извергать" близки в значении"извергнуть из общества"

Comment: Простите, но у Вас: "Изверг - старославянское ***заимствование***".

Comment: Выходит, были однокоренными уже в ст.-слав.,так как "извергать" - тоже заимствование из старославянского:     http://enc-dic.com/krylov/Izvergat-297.html    А вот туда пришли как? - об этом спор.Если одно из греч., то не однокоренные, если изверг от извергать, то однокоренные.

Comment: >Выходит, были однокоренными уже в ст.-слав.,   
  
ОК, спасибо. Вопрос, как сказал,  не праздный, это понимание смысла. Да и всего подхода. 

>А вот туда пришли как? - об этом спор  
  
Я не об этом. Эта мысль понятна.

Answer (score 1):

Слова однокоренные, а дальнейшие споры на сей счет считаю чисто "академическим" занятием, которое прикладного значения не имеет. Сам же выскажу пару идей по этому поводу для обдумывания.

Во-первых, слово "изверг" можно соотнести со словом "изгой". Какова этимология слова "изгой"? С одной стороны, напрашивается схема "изгонять"->"изгой" (что созвучно версии "извергнутый/отвергнутый обществом"->"изверг"). С другой – есть версия, что "изгой" происходит от слова "гоити" – жить, быть здоровым (ср. "Гой еси!", то есть "Будь здоров!"), то есть "изгой" – это тот, кого "выжили" из общества.

Во-вторых, мне кажется интересной версия, что слова "вергнуть, вергать" родственны словам "рыгать, рыгнуть". Возможно, был корень "рыг/рг", который обозначал "желудок", "внутренность". Отсюда "рыгнуть" – это выпустить изнутри что-то, а, например, "вергнуть" – это наоборот, что-то засунуть внутрь (тут "в/ве" может быть приставкой). Потом связь этих слов затерялась, и "вергнуть" стало самостоятельным словом, а не производным.

В связи с этим "изверг" имеет вполне понятные истоки. Как и слова "выродок", "изгой", оно имеет корень, обозначающий жизнь, рождение, и приставку, которая обозначает "отлучение" от жизни, от семьи. Вот такая версия

Answer (score 0):

В семит. ГОЙ человек другого народа. Может  гой еси  от вопроса  какого ты рода а не здоров ли.